# Connect child record to parent and grand parents

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, parent-child, sql-server-2014

Each item in the items table has one departmentID, each department id could have up to 3 grand parents. now I need to display each item with its department and  parents.

I made 3 simple joins and that did the trick.

```
SELECT        tDepartment.id, tDepartment.Name, tDepartment_1.Name AS Parent1, tDepartment_2.Name AS Parent2, tDepartment_3.Name AS Parent3
FROM            tDepartment AS tDepartment_3 RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                         tDepartment LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         tDepartment AS tDepartment_1 ON tDepartment.ParentID = tDepartment_1.id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         tDepartment AS tDepartment_2 ON tDepartment_1.ParentID = tDepartment_2.id ON tDepartment_3.id = tDepartment_2.ParentID
ORDER BY tDepartment.Name
```

My question is if that could be done in a cleaner way by using CTE or any other idea?

Comment: That code looks fine to me. The reason you might want a CTE is you wanted to have it recursively find each and every parent, then the parent of that parent and so on. If that's the case, then look up examples of recursive CTE's of which there are many. And if you don't like looking at that query you wrote, pop it in a view and then just query the view.

Comment: The right join does what you want but I would just use left joins to make it less confusing for the next person.  CTE could do the same thing but I don't think it's cleaner.

Comment: The terms "hierarchy" and "path" are applicable. They'll help you find appropriate examples. Tip: It is helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why mix right and left?

```
SELECT tDepartment.id, tDepartment.Name
      ,tDepartment_1.Name AS Parent1
      ,tDepartment_2.Name AS Parent2
      ,tDepartment_3.Name AS Parent3
  FROM tDepartment 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN tDepartment AS tDepartment_1 
       ON tDepartment.ParentID = tDepartment_1.id 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN tDepartment AS tDepartment_2 
    ON tDepartment_1.ParentID = tDepartment_2.id
  LEFT OUTER JOINtDepartment AS tDepartment_3                      
       ON tDepartment_3.id = tDepartment_2.ParentID
 ORDER BY tDepartment.Name
```